# Low level voltage is changing on I2C bus when starting communication

Tags: i2c

**The setup:**

I plugged an [STEVAL-MKI224V1](https://www.st.com/resource/en/data_brief/steval-mki224v1.pdf) board (basic eval board for baro sensor) on a nucleo F411RE. Communication happens through i2c bus.

I added 4.7k pull-up resistors on SCL and SDA.

**The wiring:**

- SDO to VDD (set i2c address)
- CS to VDD to activate i2s communication
- VDDIO to VDD to nucleo 3.3V
- GND to nucleo GND.
- SDA and SCL to nucleo.

No internal pull ups are used.

**The issue:**

As communication was not successfull on first frames, I plugged a scope on SCL and here's what I get:

[image]

On the first bytes, the low level is not +/- 0V as it should be.

**Other tests:**

- I tried a 10k pull-up, the result is the same.
- I tried with only pull-ups (without eval board), result is ok.
- I tried with another eval board for another sensor (Rohm), the result is far better but there's still a "rounded" 0. On this view, I zoomed a bit, code and i2c configuration is the same:

[image]

What did I miss?

**Pictures of the setup:**

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: The text doesn't mention it, but is ``GND`` connected between the boards? Consider editing the question to include a schematic of the connections between the boards.

Comment: Yes, it is. I did my best to improve the question but sorry, I don't have schematic.

Comment: Looking at the picture of the connections I can't see anything obviously wrong.

Comment: You were not that far: I changed GND naughty dupont cable and it works. Thanks! –

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like

- either you've got some precharged capacitive load on your SCL,
- or your SCL carries the involuntary job of exchanging current until ground potentials between two parts of your system have equalized.

Barring the possibility that you added a literal capacitor from SCL to ground or Vcc, I find the latter more plausible. Make sure you're not just connecting SCL and SDA between parts of your system – but also GND.

Comment: I changed GND naughty dupont cable and it works. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

The black ground wire is loose and makes no contact.

That will explain the waveforms and the pin looks loose on the socket.